# Is it possible to animate a group of controls in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have 3 buttons in a wpf application. Upon loading, the buttons should translate from the left side to the center of the app. I don't want to apply animations to each and every button, is there any way to group these buttons & then add the animation properties to the group which will animate the group of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the buttons in a container such as a grid and then animate the container.

An alternative would be to put the animation in a style and apply the style to the buttons, either explicitly by setting the style of each button or implicitly by setting the default style for buttons in the parent of the buttons (so again a container)

Here is an example using a style.

Unfortunately the loaded event of the window is repeatedly called so the animation keeps on going. The only solution I see is by setting a boolean after the first time and preventing the animation from occuring again.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="150" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding"
                            Value="15" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="15" />
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                     From="-150"
                                                     To="0"
                                                     RepeatBehavior="1"
                                                     Duration="0:0:2" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Button Grid.Row="0">Start</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="1">Setup</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2">Quit</Button>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I added an example using a style. Unfortunately the loaded event of the window is repeatedly called so the animation keeps on going. The only solution I see is by setting a boolean after the first time and preventing the animation from occuring again.

Comment: Thank you! A few questions though, between style and grid, which one would provide more options to animate? When is it advisable to use style over grid or vice versa?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to animate. It is also possible to add an animation in a style for the grid. It is just a matter of what you would want to reuse.